# How to know what application is injecting a script on html

Tags: script, php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out what application is injecting a javascript called http://queryjs.me/services/script.js into my pages on localhost and on my server. It only injects this script when the request takes more than 2 seconds to run, otherwise it wont get injectes. I have fresh installed my OS (MAC OS El Captain), checked all browsers but can't find any clue about what application is injecting this into my websites. I have an example here: http://teste.bigonha.com/ I get all the data from a database table and still I see this query.js thing is being injected. I have checked my ISP, DNS and checked on other computers but no luck. Even on localhost it gets injected. Does anyone have any idea how to find out what application is injecting this?

Comment: Have you checked the database tables? If you're not HTML encoding user input then someone might have been able to add some malicious content.

Comment: I am HTML encoding the output. I don't know where to investigate anymore. It loads all types of banners after this script is loaded.

Comment: Can you confirm it is only your own site that is affected? You need to systematically rule out each possible cause. For instance, have you tried creating a blank php page to see if it is affected?  There might be a php or javascript include file in your site that has been changed. You also need to check that your Apache configuration hasn't been hijacked to use malicious modules, like the cases mentioned at https://blog.sucuri.net/2013/06/new-apache-module-injection.html

Comment: I have created a blank php page without any html on it. I has only the var_dump of the variable that contains the db results. Still when i get under 6000 results I cannot see any trace of it, but any number higher than that makes my page get inject with this script.

Comment: In that case I suspect the problem is in the database.  Preventing these kinds of attacks can be very difficult, see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F

Comment: I can't thanks you enough James. That was it! Thanks for the link too.